# Ionic: Get all app content on the screen with no scrolling

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll

I'm brand new to Ionic and am creating an app, but by default, there is scrolling to the bottom of the app. When I add any HTML, it goes to the bottom where you can't see it without scrolling. How do I bring that up where its visible without scrolling and disable the scrolling all together?

Comment: I think you need to learn more about HTML, CSS and JS before starting to work with Ionic. There are a lot of good resources out there...  You may want to start @ https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: I did more digging and figured it out, thank you though.